# How to use pg \copy command to load in data while come records may conflicts unique constraint?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use \copy command to restore my table.However some of records conflicts to unique constraints since this table is not empty.

In this case, when I restore 10 records, 9 records are ok, the last conflicts, then all records restored fail.

It suggests that \copy finishes its progress in a single transaction.

How can I \copy data back ignoring records that conflicts.

Comment: You can't, `\copy` and the command it uses [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) are all or none. The best you can do is set up a staging table and `\copy` to that and then migrate the non-duplicated records to the final table.

Comment: Create a temp table then use COPY to populate is as a staging table. Then use `insert ... select ... on conflict <column(s) or constraint name> do nothing`. See documentation for [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT).